# Set of algebraic numbers is countable/denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polynomials, solution-verification

I ran into this theorem, so I tried to prove it on my own. I would like some feedback and some verification of my proof.

---

Let $A_n$ be the set of all algebraic numbers that are solutions to an $n^{th}$ order polynomial.

Define the function $f: \mathbb{Z} - \{0\} × \mathbb{Z}^{n} \rightarrow A_n$ by $f(a_0, a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) = z$ where $|z|$ is the minimum value out of all numbers $z_1, z^2, ..., z_n$ that satisfy $a_0z^n + a_1z^{n-1} + ... + a_{n-1}z + a_n = 0$ and $z$ satisfies

This function is clearly surjective, and $\mathbb{Z} - \{0\} × \mathbb{Z}^{n} \approx \mathbb{N}$ so $|\mathbb{N}| \geq |A_n|$ meaning $A_n$ is countable. Thus $\bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n$ is countable (the set of all algebraic numbers).

---

Is my proof correct? Is it wrong (and if so, why)?

Thank you very much for any response.

Comment: Practically you are mapping a polynomial with integral coefficients to its roots. A polynomial can have multiple roots. Your function is not a well defined function. For example $f(1,-3,2)$ corresponds to the polynomial equation $z^2-3z+2=0$. It has 2 roots, namely $z=1$ and $z=2$. So, what is $f(1,-3,2)$? $1$? or $2$?

Comment: @LiKwokKeung That completely slipped my mind! Thank you for pointing it out. I thought I could fix the proof as follows: I define $A_n$. But now let $S_{n,n}$ be the set of all subsets of $A_n$ with cardinality $n$, and define $f: \mathbb{Z} - \{0\} × \mathbb{Z}^{n} \rightarrow S_{n,n}$ by $f(a_0, ..., a_n) = \{z_1, ..., z_n\}$ where these are solutions to the polynomial $a_0 + a_1z + ... + a_nz^n = 0$, which is surjective. I can use induction to show that $S_{n,n} \approx A_n$, so there is a surjection from $\mathbb{Z} - \{0\} × \mathbb{Z}^{n}$ to $A_n$ and thus it is countable. Is this good?

Comment: Comment only since it's not a critique of your argument. I think the easiest proof is to note that there are only countably many polynomials with rational coefficients and each has finitely many roots.

Comment: So $S_{n,n}$ is the power set of $A_n$. The new approach is faulty because $S_{n,n}$ is not countable and your $f$ cannot be surjective. For example $1,2,3, \dots$ all belong to $A_n$ and hence $\Bbb N \subset A$. This implies that $S_{n,n}$, the power set of $A$, contains the power set of $\Bbb N$. Thus  $S_{n,n}$ is not countable.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung But $S_{n,n}$ is not the power set, it's just the set of all subsets with cardinality $n$ (for instance, the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with cardinality $1$ is given by $\{\{i\} : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$).

Comment: @Qwen_Marbell Sorry that I have misread the meaning of $S_{n,n}$. I should be more careful.

Comment: I still have questions though. Let's take $n=2$ and consider $S_{2,2}$ for simplicity. Here are the questions: (1) What is $f(1,-2,1)$? Note that  $z^2-2z+1=0$ has repeated roots $-1$. Is $f(1,-2,1)$ equal to  $\{ 1\}$ or $\{ 1, 1\}$? (2) We know that both $\sqrt 3$ and 1 belong to $A_2$ and hence $\{\sqrt 3, 1 \} \in S_{2,2}$. But what is the preimage of $\{\sqrt 3, 1 \}$? It seems that no degree 2 polynomial with integral coefficients can have $\sqrt 3 $ and $ 1$ as roots.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung I see. I'm thinking that $A_n$ is defined so vaguely by me which is why it's difficult coming up with some $f$. Here's a change I made to the proof: Let $A_n$ be the set of subsets of A (set of algebraic numbers) such that each set in $A_n$ contains the roots of some $n^{th}$ order polynomial with integer coefficients. Define $f: \mathbb{Z} - \{0\} × \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow A_n$ by $f(a_0, ..., a_n) = B$ where $B = \{z \in A: a_0 + a_1z + ... + a_nz^n = 0\}$. This is a surjection and so $|N| \ge |A_n|$. Thus $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n = A$ is countable. Does this work?

Comment: $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}An$ is a set of sets and $A$ is a set of numbers and they cannot be equal to each other. For example, $\{ 1, 2\} \in A_2 $  and hence $\{ 1, 2\} \in \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N}An$,  but $\{ 1, 2\} \notin A $ .

Comment: Indeed from your definition, we should have the following equality:  $$A= \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \left (\bigcup_{B \in A_n} B \right )$$

Comment: If I am right, you may proceed from $$A= \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \left (\bigcup_{B \in A_n} B \right )$$ to prove the final assertion.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Oh right I meant the union of the elements of $A_n$ and then proceeding to take the union for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which is easy to show is countable. Thank you so much for helping me all the way through!!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your function is not well defined. The idea in this proof is the concept of index of polynomial. Given a polynomial $p(x)=a_0+\cdots+a_nx^n$ the index is defined as the sum $\vert a_0\vert+\cdots+\vert a_n\vert+n$. Since for each natural number $k>0$, the set of polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $a_n>0$ which index is $k$ is finite. For example:
$$k=2\;: x\\
k=3\;: x^2,2x,x+1,x-1$$
Now we considerate the enumeration of the algebraic real numbers based on the increasing values of the index begining with the usual ordering of the roots for the polynomials of that index, and discounting the roots that had appeared before, i.e.:

$$0_{2}<-1,1_{3}<-2,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},2_{4}<\cdots$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

First we let $P_n$ be the set of degree $n$ polynomials with integral coefficients, and define $$f_n: \Bbb Z-\{ 0\} \times \Bbb Z^n  \to P_n$$ by $$f_n(a_0, \dots , a_n)=a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\dots + a_n$$ Then  $f_n$ is obviously bijective and the fact that $\Bbb Z-\{ 0\} \times \Bbb Z^n $ is countable implies that $P_n$ is countable.

Next we let $P$ be the set of polynomials with integral coefficients. Then $$P=\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N 
 }P_n$$
$P$ is countable because it is a countable union of countable sets.

Third, for each polynomial $p_k \in P, k \in \Bbb N$, we define $$A_{p_k} = \{z: p_k(z)=0\}$$

Since $A_{p_k}$ is the set of roots of $p_k(z)=0$, $A_{p_k}$ is finite.

Finally let $A$ be the set of algebraic numbers, then
$$A= \bigcup _{p_k \in P} A_{p_k}$$

We can now say that $A$ is countable because it is countable union of finite sets.